# is it possible to share an "unmanaged" shared memory pointer using boost interprocess?

Tags: c++, boost, process, g++, ipc

My case is very rare.
I have a library called libtest.so. It has a function called void test1(int **p);

```
void test1(int **p)
{
   *p = (int *) malloc(4 * sizeof(int));
}
```

I can get the integer array by this way

```
int p = NULL;
test0(&p);
```

For some reason, I don't want to dlopen() it in process A.
Instead, I dlopen("libtest.so") in process B and create a managed_shared_memory.
The process A connects to the managed_shared_memory.

The process B calls the test0(&p) to obtain an integer array.
It is possible to share this pointer p(unmanaged shared memory) from process B to process A ?

I tried to pass the addr of p by pointer of pointer of the managed_shared_memory from process B to process A. But It didn't work.

```
// process B
struct shm_object
{
    offset_ptr<int *> pp;
    shm_object() :{};
};
...
shm = managed_shared_memory(open_or_create, INTERPROCESS_MEMORY_NAME,MANAGED_MEMORY_INITIAL_SIZE);
s_mem_object = shm.find_or_construct<shm_object>(SHARED_MEMORY_OBJECT_1_NAME)

int p;
test0(&p);

s_mem_object->pp = static_cast<int **>(shm.allocate(sizeof(int *)));
int **pp = static_cast<int **>(s_mem_object->p.get());

pp[0] = p;   // save address of the p to pp
...
```

```
// process A
...
 int **pp = static_cast<int**>(s_mem_object->pp.get());
 for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
 {
    printf("from process-A %d\n", (*pp)[i]);
 }
...
```

Sure, the standard way to make this scenario works is

1. to get the integer array
2. allocate a piece of memory
3. copy the integer array to the managed_shared_memory

But, it real case scenario, the memory structs are complicated. A lot of efforts have to be spent on the implementation of deep-copy.

Is there any workaround ?

Comment: The pointer to the "unmanaged" memory as you call it has no value to the other process so, you'll have to put the actual data in shared memory, or, only let one process interact with the data directly and talk to that process via some IPC mechanism to read/write what you want.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I believe it's correct to say "Non shared (allocated with malloc in that case) memory of the first process has no value in another".

Comment: @Dmitry Yes, I was trying to use OPs lingo which was probably a bad idea :-) Your version is better.

Comment: @prgbenz if you can't update you `test1` function, I suppose there is no legal way to achieve what you want w/o creating shared memory region and copying everything into it. Well, if you can update it, you can just create shared memory inside it directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `test1` cannot be (made) allocator-aware you cannot reliably/usefully share a pointer with another process.

Note that you **can** hand it off to another process and receive it back usefully. I'd suggest to send it as `ptrdiff_t` instead of the raw pointer to avoid accidental use as a pointer.